# Calculating Inverse PDF of Z term minus a value

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I'm finding myself a pick stuck with this, I'm only used to seeing pdf's in terms of $\Phi\left(Z_\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)$, but I've come across the below and am not sure how to calculate.

$\Phi\left(Z_\frac{.05}{2}-3\right)=0.149$

Comment: You are mixing up PDF and CDF. $\Phi$ is customarily used for standard normal CDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R statistical software `pnorm` (without modifying arguments) is
the standard normal CDF $\Phi$ and `qnorm` is the inverse CDF or
quantile function. In R your computation is as follows:

```
q = qnorm(.975);  q
## 1.959964
pnorm(q)
## 0.975
pnorm(q - 3)
## 0.1491616
```

Notice that the notation $Z_{.025} = 1.96$ involves cutting 2.5% from the
*upper* tail of standard normal. This notation is often used in connection
with printed tables.

$P(Z > 1.96) = 0.025,$ whereas $P(Z \le 1.96) = 0.975.$

In the figure below, the area under the density curve to the right of the red dashed line is 0.025
and the area to the left of the purple dotted line is 0.149.

[image]

```
# code for figure
curve(dnorm(x), -3, 3, lwd=2, ylab="PDF", xlab="z", main="Standard Normal Density")
abline(h=0, col="green2")
abline(v = 1.96, col="red", lty="dashed")
abline(v = 1.96-3, col="purple", lty="dotted")
```